# how to join three tables without duplication in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables...
1) t_quoteMaster

```
quoteId  quoteNo  quoteDate  custName  itemName  itemQty  itemPrice  itemToal  
  10        2     17/10/17    cust1     item1       2        100       200   
  11        2     17/10/17    cust1     item2       5        20        100
```

2) t_custMaster

```
custId  custName  custAddress  custGSTIN  custPhone
  10     cust1        US       123456789  123456789  
  11     cust2        UK       987654321  987654321
```

3) t_productMaster

```
productId  productName  productHSN  productUnit  productPrice
    15       item1      1111111111      kg           100  
    16       item2      2222222222     gram          20  
    17       item3      3333333333      kg           50
```

now i want to join tables on custName and itemName..
the result should be..

```
quoteId  quoteNo  quoteDate  custName  itemName  itemQty  itemPrice  itemToal  productHSN  productUnit  custAddress  custGSTIN  
  10        2     17/10/17    cust1     item1       2        100       200     1111111111      kg           US       123456789
  11        2     17/10/17    cust1     item2       5        20        100     2222222222     gram          US       123456789
```

i need to select (**custAddress** and **custGSTIN**) from **t_custMaster** And (**productHSN** and **productUnit**) from **t_productMaster** on the basis of **custName** and **itemName** respectively from t_quoteMaster and attach it to the end of t_quoteMaster..

I tried below query but if gives duplication of rows..

```
SELECT t_quoteMaster.*,
t_productMaster.productHSN,
t_productMaster.productUnit,
t_custMaster.custAddress,
t_custMaster.custGSTIN 
FROM t_quoteMaster
INNER JOIN t_productMaster
ON t_quoteMaster.itemName = t_productMaster.productName
INNER JOIN t_custMaster
ON t_quoteMaster.custName = t_custMaster.custName
where t_quoteMaster.quoteNo = '2'
```

Comment: Can you show the duplicate results?

Comment: This example would not give duplication...

Comment: That's why I want to see the duplicate line that the OP is talking about.. I can't see it duplicating either.

Comment: you are right Harry and kbball that's mine silly mistake..

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplication when joining in a one to many basis is a common issue. You can use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_quoteMaster.*,
t_productMaster.productHSN,
t_productMaster.productUnit,
t_custMaster.custAddress,
t_custMaster.custGSTIN 
FROM t_quoteMaster
INNER JOIN t_productMaster
ON t_quoteMaster.itemName = t_productMaster.productName
INNER JOIN t_custMaster
ON t_quoteMaster.customerName = t_custMaster.custName
where quoteNo = '2'
```